# Jenkins: Active Choice Parameter Script Does Not Recognize HTTPS Request shell script, curl nor URL.openConnection() calls

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

So I have a docker container that runs jenkins locally. Active Choice plugin is installed where I can add scripts to Active Choices Parameter. When I write the script to return a list of arbitrary strings, it will do so. I'm under the impression that it also supports http/https requests and have  found several examples of it doing so. I want to dynamically populate the combobox with the results of a list of strings that is parsed from my json response yet I can't even get it to execute the https request. Originally I was trying to follow this [example](https://kublr.com/blog/advanced-jenkins-groovy-scripting-for-live-fetching-of-docker-images/)

I have tried

```
def response = sh(script: 'curl -X GET -H "x-api-key: data" -H "content-type: application/json" https://site/api/path', returnStdout: true)
```

```
def response = ["curl", "-X", "GET", "https://site/api/path", "-H", "accept: application/json", "-H", "x-api-key: data"].execute().text
```

```
def http_client = new URL("https://site/api/path").openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
```

```
def url = new URL("https://site/api/path")
def http_client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()
```

There seems to be no way to debug this other than going by one line at a time. I test it with this which will return 1 in my list as expected but as soon as I call `url.openConnection()` it will fail.

```
def url = new URL("https://site/api/path")

return [1]
```

So what gives? I don't have any import statements but I didn't think I needed any. When I had more code, even with `import groovy.json.JsonSlurper` when I instantiate `JsonSlurper` it would complain about that.

Comment: Wow I feel so dumb but I figured it out! I had the `Use Groovy Sandbox` checked. Unchecking that, `Approve Script` and `Save/Apply` allows it to work.